# JavaScript - variable changes its value when I re-assign it

Tags: javascript

How can I keep the variables in the event listener to avoid being overwritten?
Below is an example. It will alert twice of 'second', instead of 'first' then 'second'

```
var firstVar = 'first';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert(firstVar);
});

var firstVar = 'second';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert(firstVar);
});
```

I have tried, as below too.

```
var firstVar = 'first';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var temp = firstVar;
    alert(temp);
});

var firstVar = 'second';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var temp = firstVar;
    alert(temp);
});
```

I event tried to use bind(this) but none of them is working.
Is there a way for this to work or there's no way it will works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

since you have declared the same variable twice so after page load only last on will be available .it is like you have assigned new value to it so you can not see `first` in alert.

**you have to do something like this:**

```
var firstVar1 = 'first';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert(firstVar1);
});

var firstVar = 'second';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert(firstVar);
});
```

**or better add both statement in single load event. like this:**

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
  var firstVar = 'first';  
    alert(firstVar);
    var firstVar = 'second';
    alert(firstVar);

});
```

**or you can do this:**

```
var firstVar = 'first';

window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    alert(firstVar);
mymethod();

});

function mymethod(){

    var firstVar = 'second';
    alert(firstVar);
}
```

**or similar to your implementation:**

```
var firstVar = 'first';
localStorage.setItem("data1",firstVar);
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var first = localStorage.getItem("data1");
    alert(first);

});

var firstVar = 'second';
localStorage.setItem("data2",firstVar);
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var first = localStorage.getItem("data2");
    alert(first);

});
```

Comment: Yes you are using the event listener for load asking for firstVar.  since the document can only load one time you get the same result.

Comment: @NinjoeQuah you can not do this on window load event better write some other event on your page and implement it.

Comment: ok i understand what you are trying to tell me, but I cant change how the variable is being declared, it has to be that way only. So was looking way to make it works. Thanks

Comment: @Ninjoe Quah i don't know why you want to implement like this you can try the edited one in last which is some what similar to your implementation.

Comment: erm..because my js will have only one firstVar and one event load only. But sometimes I will have to call this js twice or more, therefore the firstVar will be overwritten, they are 2 load event from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the event listener for load asking for `firstVar`.

*The document can only load one time* so you get the same result.

**This is how you do it**

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    var firstVar = 'First';
    alert(firstVar);

    var firstVar = 'Second';
    alert(firstVar);
});
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to said, but I have to do it that way. So I was looking for a way to make that works. Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: @NinjoeQuah It's impossible to do it that way.